# How to launch thread from class constructor with std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have this constructor that initializes the `bar` member with 0 and starts a thread:

```
Foo::Foo() :
  bar(0)
{
   std::thread threadloop = std::thread(loop); //create a thread with the loop function
   threadloop.join();
}
```

And this `loop()` function from the `Foo class`:

```
void Foo::loop()
{
   while (true)
   {
      bar++;
      //do more stuff...
   }
}
```

The compiler complains that the `loop` method must be `static`...
But if I put it `static`, how can I access the `Foo` private members that are not `static`? (and must not be static).

**EDIT:**

If I use like this, it won't compile either:

```
std::thread threadloop(&Foo::loop, Foo());
```

**Error**: Use of deleted function.

I want to call this from my `constructor`, and not from outside my class.

Comment: This is a repeat. Look for other instances of this topic on SO.